# Reset kubeadmin password in OKD 4.7

Tags: redhat, kubernetes, openshift

I tried to find password in `.openshift_install.log` file and I found something but it didn't work. I tried to `oc get secrets kubeadmin -n kube-system -ojsonpath='{.data.kubeadmin}' | base64 --decode && echo ""` and it didn't work neither. How can I reset kubeadmin password with oc ??
Thanks

Comment: are you sure you are using password? default K8S authentication is based on  certificate authentication. I'm not sure about OpenShift, since not worked with it.

Comment: Hi Mohammad Mousavi, what is the output of `oc get secrets kubeadmin -n kube-system`? `oc get secrets kubeadmin -n kube-system -o yaml`? Is the secret there?

Answer (score 0):

**To find the encrypted password**

The password for the kubeadmin user is stored in the `kubeadmin` Secret in the namespace `kube-system`. You should be able to see the bcrypt encoded value with `oc get secret kubeadmin -n kubesystem -ojsonpath='{.data.kubeadmin}' | base64 -d`. The encrypted password starts with `$2y$10$`, specifying that it is using the bcrypt algorithm with a cost of 10.

To reset the password you'll need to generate a new encoded password and update the secret. Please note the password is required to be [at least 23 characters](https://github.com/openshift/oauth-apiserver/blob/master/vendor/github.com/openshift/library-go/pkg/authentication/bootstrapauthenticator/bootstrap.go#L27-L29).

**Steps to replace the password**

- Generate a new random password.
- Encrypt the password using the `htpasswd` utility.
- Now base64 encode that encoded password with `base64 -w0`. The `-w0` is to disable line wrapping.
- Patch the secret in the cluster with `oc patch secret/kubeadmin -n kube-system -p '{"data": {"kubeadmin": "[value for the base64 encoded, bcrypt encrypted password]"}}'`.

**A full example**

- The new password will be `w9dYJ-00Je7-K2A0H-ED5ku-6Sdvz`
- Encrypt with `htpasswd -bnBC 10 "" w9dYJ-00Je7-K2A0H-ED5ku-6Sdvz | tr -d ':\n'`
- Encode the result `echo $2y$10$c9zxzleI5pvNXdWNHD3bT.vdqpJY2cI752YLswMydZR2VoIudbtti | base64 -w0`
- Apply the patch to cluster with `oc patch secret/kubeadmin -n kube-system -p '{"data": {"kubeadmin": "JDJ5JDEwJGM5enh6bGVJNXB2TlhkV05IRDNiVC52ZHFwSlkyY0k3NTJZTHN3TXlkWlIyVm9JdWRidHRpCg=="}}'`
- You should now be able to login to the cluster using your new password.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's remind that if you follow carefully installation steps, there will be a moment you have to install the 'oc' CLI tool and use it to ['login' to your cluster](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.12/installing/installing_vsphere/installing-vsphere.html#cli-logging-in-kubeadmin_installing-vsphere) via:

```
$ export KUBECONFIG=<installation_directory>/auth/kubeconfig
# replace <installation_directory> by the directory where you created your
#   installation artefacts with the openshift-install prog
$ oc whoami
```

that shall confirm you are in as 'system:admin'

From that point, finding the URL path to the web console is quite easy, just do the variant:

```
$ oc whoami --show-console
```

and there's too a file dropped by the installer in your <installation_directory>:

```
$ cat <installation_directory>/auth/kubeadmin-password
```

That last file is actually seen as a security weakness and may disappear in future releases (RedHat recommends you to [remove that account](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.12/authentication/remove-kubeadmin.html) ).

Hence there's an alternative way to define a few additional 'admin' user accounts from the 'oc' command line, which is anyhow far better for sharing OC Cluster administration tasks with colleagues, each with one's identity instead of sharing the kubeadmin password, and also with a login method that won't depend from the availability of an IDP in case the later is unavailable for whatever reason (you can combine many  authentication means).

Route path:

1. add a ['htpasswd' identity provider](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.12/authentication/identity_providers/configuring-htpasswd-identity-provider.html) to the built-in authentication pod
2. [add the 'cluster-admin' role to the users](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.12/authentication/using-rbac.html#creating-cluster-role_using-rbac) so created

Please review detailed steps in the above linked docs to understand what you are doing. Here is a brief summary.

```
#ensure you are properly logged in for the next 'oc' CLI commands
$ export KUBECONFIG=<installation_directory>/auth/kubeconfig
$ oc whoami
   system:admin
#ensure the authentication operator is up and running
$ oc get clusteroperators
   NAME                                       VERSION   AVAILABLE   etc...  
   authentication                             4.12.0    True        etc...
   ...
#ensure authentication API pods are deployed
$ oc get pods -n openshift-authentication
   NAME                               READY   STATUS    etc...
   oauth-openshift-84955b4d7c-4d2dc   1/1     Running   
   oauth-openshift-84955b4d7c-4wx8v   1/1     Running   
   oauth-openshift-84955b4d7c-7pnqj   1/1     Running  

# create an initial htpasswd file (if you already have one, or want to update passwords, omit the 'c' arg)
$ htpasswd -cB users.htpasswd <myLoginNameHere>
   # your are prompted for a password twice
   # repeat the command for additional users' login names
# prepare the file for inclusion as a string attribute in YAML
$ base64 -w0 users.htpasswd >users.htpasswd.b64
# edit a inject-htpass-secret.yaml file with the following content
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Secret
   metadata:
     name: htpass-secret
     namespace: openshift-config
   type: Opaque
   data:
     htpasswd: 'YmVybmFyZG... you paste here between quotes the B64 content of your users.htpasswd.b64 file ... ZtQ1MwaEdDCg=='
# create or update the secret 'htpass-secret' with the new htpasswd artefact
$ oc apply -f inject-htpass-secret.yaml
```

if you just need to update users/passwords in a existing config, the above is sufficient.

```
#check you don't have yet a htpasswd identity provider configured
$ oc describe oauth.config.openshift.io/cluster
# or alternatively:
$ oc edit oauth.config.openshift.io cluster
   # and you shall see that the Spec attribute is an empty object
#Then, add the provider. Edit an config-OAuth-id-provider.yaml file as below.
# you can only customize the name for your provider, here 'htpasswd_provider'
   apiVersion: config.openshift.io/v1
   kind: OAuth
   metadata:
     name: cluster
   spec:
     identityProviders:
     - name: htpasswd_provider
       mappingMethod: claim
       type: HTPasswd
       htpasswd:
         fileData:
           name: htpass-secret
# and apply (or update the htpasswd_provider ! ...or add it!)
$ oc apply -f config-OAuth-id-provider.yaml
```

Last, add a cluster-admin role to users

```
#each user must login once first, 
   # which is the way for the authentication operator to discover that a new user exists
#then, add the cluster role
$ oc adm policy add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-admin <userLoginNameHere>
#if you are already logged in, you may see your web console updating its display instantly
```

Enjoy local console logins!